# Convolution with Cotangent function

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, convolution

$f(x)$ is $C^1$. Let interval $I = [0, 2\pi]$ and $I = I_1\cup I_2, I_1\cap I_2 = \emptyset$. Now suppose that $f(x) \equiv 0, \forall x\in I_1$  and the convolution $g(x) = \int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\cot((x-t)/2)\,dt \equiv 0,\forall x\in I_2$. Can we prove that $f(x)\equiv 0, \forall x\in I$ or find a counterexample?

Comment: Are $I_1,I_2$ intervals? Is $f$ periodic?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, $I_1,I_2$ are intervals. But $f$ does not have to be periodic (though it can be) since I only care about the values on interval $[0, 2\pi]$.